# error[E0502]: cannot borrow `cloned_game` as immutable because it is also borrowed as mutable

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I'm new to Rust. I'm trying to solve a problem using recursion. Within the recursive function, I clone the state of the game, then take each pair of elements from a vector and mutate them using `try_add_to()`, then check if the game is solved.

```
fn try_find_solution(game: &GameState) -> Option<GameState> {
    let mut cloned_game = game.clone();

    for split_index in 1..cloned_game.cups.len() - 1 {
        // Need two mutable references from the vector. Use split_at_mut() to allow this.
        let (a, b) = cloned_game.cups.split_at_mut(split_index);
        let first_cup = a.last_mut().unwrap();

        for second_cup in b.iter_mut() {
            if first_cup.try_add_to(second_cup) || second_cup.try_add_to(first_cup) {
                if cloned_game.is_solved() {
                    return Some(cloned_game);
                }
                else {
                    // let solution = try_find_solution(&cloned_game);
                    // @TODO.
                }
            }
        }
    }

    None
}
```

I'm running into the following error.

```
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `cloned_game` as immutable because it is also borrowed as mutable
  --> src/main.rs:31:20
   |
26 |         let (a, b) = cloned_game.cups.split_at_mut(split_index);
   |                      ---------------- mutable borrow occurs here
...
30 |             if first_cup.try_add_to(second_cup) || second_cup.try_add_to(first_cup) {
   |                --------- mutable borrow later used here
31 |                 if cloned_game.is_solved() {
   |                    ^^^^^^^^^^^ immutable borrow occurs here
```

I think I understand why this error is occuring, but don't know how to fix it without a complete redesign of the solution. Is there anything I can do?

Answer (score 1):

If this is your attempt at brute forcing something, I might not use recursion. You may hit the recursion limit for anything but the most trivial solutions. Also, you're going to have to do an excessive amount of cloning as each stack makes its own clone of the game state.

As for your original problem, the best way is to avoid having to hold these references at the same time.

For example, this won't compile:

```rust
fn hello_world(s: &mut [u8]){
    let (a,b) = s.split_at_mut(1);
    let c = s.len();
    drop((a,b,c));
}
```

...but this does:

```rust
fn hello_world(s: &mut [u8]){
    let (a,b) = s.split_at_mut(1);
    drop((a,b));
    
    let c = s.len();
    drop(c);
}
```

...because we're not forcibly holding `a` and `b` to the end. If you can extract the `.is_solved()` call to outside the loop, that should work.